# C# Action delegate for API controllers to talk to Services

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, delegates

I have seen this approach before where an API controller uses wrapper that puts a unitofwork object in a Action delegate. Then when the delegate is used, it talks to a service layer method that accepts a model and returns Void. The idea is to pass in the model from the outside scope.

```
//Controller Base
public void Wrapper(Action<UnitOfWork> action)
{
    action(new UnitOfWork());
}

//Controller 
[HttpPost]
[Route("user")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Member))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostUser(Member user)
{
    Wrapper(uw => { service.Get(uw, user); });
    return Ok(user);
}

//Service
public void Get(UnitOfWork uw, Member model)
{
    model = uw.MemberRepository.Get(u => u.UserId == id).FirstOrDefault();

    //Member m = uw.MemberRepository.Get(u => u.UserId == id).FirstOrDefault();
    //model.Created = m.Created;
    //model.ExpiryInDays = m.ExpiryInDays;
    //model.Id = m.Id;
}
```

I feel this is a nice approach and I have seen it in projects before... however when I try the above, the object on the controller does not reflect the change made on the service.

Comment: Make sure ApplicationUser is declared as `class` and not `struct`

Comment: thanks, I can confirm that it is declared as a Class. I have tried other objects declared as Classes and none work

Comment: I updated my code to reflect my problem as I know understand. I am trying to change the model with a data Get from a EF repository. the commented out code works. the EF code does not reflect the changes on the Controller side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to change the address the model parameter points to.

Even though Member is a reference type and you can modify it inside the method ,you can't modify the address it points to.
(You can modify the parameter's address but not the argument's address)
If you need that you have to use the ref keyword

Check the following example

```
namespace Test
{
    using System;
    public class MyObject
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyObject obj = new MyObject() { Value = "original" };

            Console.WriteLine(obj.Value);
            Change2(obj);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Value);
            Change3(ref obj);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Value);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Change2(MyObject obj)
        {
            obj = new MyObject() { Value="You can't see this outside the method" };

            Console.WriteLine("Inside Change 2 "+obj.Value);
        }

        private static void Change3(ref MyObject obj)
        {
            obj = new MyObject() { Value = "You CAN see this outside the method" };

            Console.WriteLine("Inside Change 3 " + obj.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And there it is! I though the ref keyword was for Value type only. nice. So to sum it up. In the commented out code, I was only changing the values of the object but its memory address was always the same so positive result. But then trying to get data from the repository it is effectively applies the memory address of the returned object so it can not reflect elsewhere. Thanks for your support on this!